# Manipulating calendars in R

Tags: r

I have an input table, which looks something like:

```
dataframe[,'Date']:
Field
'20-Jun'
'25-Jun'
'28-Jun'
'30-Jun'
```

I'd like to work out the number of days each one has since the start of the year.

Currently I am partially solving this problem (only for the first element) by doing:

```
this_year<-'2015'
calmap<-data.frame(c('Jan','Feb'....),c(1:12))
colnames(colmap)<-... #a little bit of tidy up
tmp.val<-as.character(dataframe[,'Date'])
splitcal<-strsplit(tmp.val,'-')
month.val<-calmap[calmap$Month==splitcal[[1]][2],'Month_Num']
first.date<-as.Date(paste(paste(this_year,month.val,sep='-'),splitcal[[1]][1],sep='-'))
first.jan<-as.Date(paste(format(first.date,'%Y'),'-01-01',sep=''))
```

This only solves it, however, for the first element of the `dataframe[,'Date']` object, and my attempts to generalise it (by converting `[[1]]->[[]]`) dont work.

Can anyove give me a tip please? The path I'm working down right now might be completely wrong.

tl;dr I have a `dataframe[,'Date']` object which contains values such as `Jun-20`, and would like to convert these into days relative to `01/01/thisyear`.

Comment: Check out `lubridate`, it makes working with dates very easy. Though in `base`, `difftime` will tell you exactly what you want if you pass it two dates (coerce your strings with `as.Date("...", format = "...")`).

Comment: Hey. I've used other functions before to calculate the difference between two dates i.e. `x<-as.integer(as.Date('2015-07-01')-as.Date('2015-01-01')`, but the struggle here is converting a DD-MMM into a date. It would be fine if it wasnt `May`, but instead, `5`.

Also trying to do this in `base R`.

Comment: `difftime(as.Date("Jun-20", format = "%b-%d"), as.Date("2015-01-01"))`?

Comment: Sorry. The problem is that my dates are actually `31-May`, not `May-31` - which is not a format handled by the `as.Date()` function.

Comment: Swap the format to `%d-%b`. The format argument tells R how to parse the string - `%b` is the code for month by 3 letter abbreviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base`

`difftime(as.Date(dataframe[,'Date'], format = "%d-%b"), as.Date("2015-01-01"))`

should do the trick.

The date is assumed to be the current year if not told otherwise.

Comment: Hero, that does the trick. I did not realise we could use the format switch on `as.Date()`. Thanks.

Comment: @Henry for reference, https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html is the different ways to parse datetimes.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english")
dataframe <- data.frame(Date = c('Jun-20', 'Jun-25', 'Jun-28', 'Jun-30'))
dates <- as.Date(paste(dataframe[, "Date"], format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")), format = "%b-%d %Y")
as.numeric(format(dates, "%j"))
# [1] 171 176 179 181
```

Comment: Sorry. The problem is that my dates are actually `31-May`, not `May-31` - which is not a format handled by the `as.Date()` function.

Comment: Akhil solved my problem - basically I did not realise we could use the format switch on `as.Date()`. Thanks.